# Get list of all charges for a customer and separate one time vs subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I get a list of all charges for a customer using this:

```
$charges = $stripeClient->charges->all(['customer' => $user->stripe_id]);
```

However, I want to separate single charges (one-time) from recurring ones (received as subscription to a price/item).

Is this possible to do using API or I have to think about workaround?

Answer (score 1):

When you list Charges on a Customer, it lists all Charges, one-time as well as recurring Charges.

On Charges originating from Subscriptions, those should have an `invoice` field.

So you could auto-paginate [0] through those Charges, the ones with `invoice` would be recurring and the ones without would be one-time.

There isn't a way to fetch only Charges resulting from Subscriptions vs one-time.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto?lang=ruby